# Several 'onclick' events for 1 div (change div id)

Tags: javascript, events, onclick

I have 2 divs.

Once 1 of the 2 divs has been selected, the 'id' of each will change to either divActive, or divInactive so the active one can be highlighted using css.

Is it possible to do this even though i already have an 'onclick' action associated with each div?

Here are my divs:

```
<div class="statusOption" onclick="loadXMLDoc('indexEveryone')">Everyone, everywhere</div>
<div class="statusOption" onclick="loadXMLDoc('indexFav')">Favourites Only</div>
```

Here is my current javascript:

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(pageName)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("centreCont").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","../home/" + pageName + ".php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: U should consider using jQuery

Comment: You should change the class instead of the ID.

Comment: @eric.itzhak I disagree completely

Comment: @Zeaklous: It doesn't have to be jQuery, but in this day and age there is not much of an argument for using vanilla JS over a framework when  it comes to DOM manipulation or AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use jQuery you don't have to. Here is a pure javascript version. Notice it toggles an `active` class, not an ID.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var everyone = document.getElementById('everyone'),
        favorites = document.getElementById('favorites');

    everyone.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexEveryone');
        var myClasses = everyone.className,
            otherClasses = favorites.className;
        if (myClasses.contains("active"))
        {
            everyone.className = 'statusOption';
        }
        else if (otherClasses.contains("active")) {
            everyone.className = 'statusOption active';
            favorites.className = 'statusOption';
        }
        else {
            everyone.className = 'statusOption active';
        }
    }

    favorites.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexFav');        
        var myClasses = favorites.className,
            otherClasses = everyone.className;
        if (myClasses.contains("active"))
        {
            favorites.className = 'statusOption';
        }
        else if (otherClasses.contains("active")) {
            favorites.className = 'statusOption active';
            everyone.className = 'statusOption';
        }
        else {
            favorites.className = 'statusOption active';
        }
    }

    function loadXMLDoc(event) {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("centreCont").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","../home/" + pageName + ".php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

**Edit to accommodate requests in comments:** If you always want one to be active it shortens the code a lot. Here is the updated code. Just make sure you give `everyone` the active class to start in your HTML

```
window.onload = function () {
    var everyone = document.getElementById('everyone'),
        favorites = document.getElementById('favorites');

    everyone.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexEveryone');
        var otherClasses = favorites.className;
        if (otherClasses.contains("active")) {
            everyone.className = 'statusOption active';
            favorites.className = 'statusOption';
        }
    }

    favorites.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexFav');        
        var otherClasses = everyone.className;
        if (otherClasses.contains("active")) {
            favorites.className = 'statusOption active';
            everyone.className = 'statusOption';
        }
    }

    function loadXMLDoc(pageName) {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("centreCont").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","../home/" + pageName + ".php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have more that one function call in onclick.

However, you should not change the id of the elements, but add or remove a class instead.

Also, you should really consider using something like jQuery, which would make your code much more concise:

```
<div id="everyone" class="statusOption" onclick="loadXMLDoc('indexEveryone')">Everyone, everywhere</div>
<div id="favorites" class="statusOption" onclick="loadXMLDoc('indexFav')">Favourites Only</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#everyone').on('click', loadXMLDoc, 'indexEveryone');
   $('#favorites').on('click', loadXMLDoc, 'indexFav');
   $('div.statusOption').on('click', function(){
     $('div.statusOption').removeClass('active'); 
     $(this).addClass('active');
   });
});


function loadXMLDoc(event)
{
$.ajax({
  url: "../home/" + event.data + ".php",
  type: "GET",
  success: function(result){ $("#centreCont").html(result); }
});  
</script>
```

Comment: I agree with the first two points, not the third. Implementing a whole library for this small function is far from necessary

Comment: @Zeaklous Unless we're talking about high performance application, and considering that most likley he'll need other features sooner or later, Yes, there is a need.

Comment: @Zeaklous: You don't need to 'implement' jQuery. Especially when deployed via a CDN, jQuery does hardly add to page load times at all. Why would you write your own AJAX implementation with allowances for browsers like IE6 if you can have it a practically no cost? Not to mention that your code becomes a lot easier to read and maintain.